# What does "higgledy-piggledy" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What does "higgledy-piggledy" mean?  Does higgledy and piggledy means anything separately?  How to use these two words?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you could have Googled this. Unless you have a more indepth question, I'm voting to close as general reference. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/higgledy-piggledy

Comment: It means helter-skelter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/higgledy-piggledy) it means *in an untidy way that lacks any order*.

For more definitions, and usage examples, try [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/higgledy-piggledy).

Comment: Or, try [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com).  OneLook will return the results from several online dictionaries all at once, including links, along with a brief meaning derived from these other sources.  (If everyone checked OneLook first, we'd have far fewer questions closed here).

Answer (score 1):

It can also mean a type of humorous verse, in which the first line is supposed to be "higgledy piggledy" or some other (often nonsense) word(s) of the same meter. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dactyl) for a number of examples.